Help writing a Microsoft Intune compliance script for macOS
May I please get assistance with a Microsoft Intune compliance script for macOS.
If (app) is not installed set, device as non compliant.
This is the srcipt I tried but its isn't working. I want to upload the script to intune so that intune can mark devices without Apex installed as non compliant.
#!/bin/sh
#Enter the Name of the Application here Apex One (Mac)
Security Agent="/Applications/Apex One (Mac) Security Agent"
echo $Apex One (Mac) Security Agent
#Check if Directory Exist
if [ ! -d $ApplicationName ]; then 
    echo $ApplicationName "is not installed"
    exit
fi
echo $ApplicationName " is installed"


Can you please fix the code formatting with an edit. Also, what does „not working“ mean: do you get an error message?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@nohillside I am not sure I follow when you say "fix the code formatting with an edit" I am completely new to this. but I am not getting an error. i say its not working because devices on intune with the installed app are not coming up as non compliant

Do the scripts at https://github.com/microsoft/shell-intune-samples/tree/master/macOS help?
See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/apps/macos-shell-scripts and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/fundamentals/deployment-guide-platform-macos
How does the script set the non-compliant state? Is it based on the script's exit status?

There is a help button when editing a post, which explains how to format the content so it is readable.

Even igoring the edit-related issue on line 3 of the script, there seems to be some confusion about variable names (is it agent, apex, or ApplicationName?

Based on the behaviour of a Microsoft Linux sample compliance script, it appears a compliance script writes output to a log file. Maybe the output is expected to be parsable JSON?
The script below works on macOS and detects if the application Power Manager.app exists in the /Applications folder. As in the linked example, the result is written to compliance.log in the user's home folder; this is not idiomatic for macOS but it matches the example:
#!/bin/bash

# Redirect output to a file: https://serverfault.com/questions/103501
exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
exec 1>>"$HOME/compliance.log" 2>&1

# Write prefix to log
echo "$(date) | Starting compliance script"
echo "{"

# Does something exist at the given absolute path?
if [ -e "/Applications/Power Manager.app" ]; then
    echo "Power Manager is installed"
else
    echo "Power Manager is not installed"
fi

# Write suffix to log
echo "}"
echo "$(date) | Ending compliance script"


Thanks Graham, I am looking for a script that will mark a device as non compliant in intune and not one that writes the uotp to the users device

Please could you edit the question to include a link to an example script that does this on another platform. A link to the specific intune documentation may also help attract better answers.
